# 3D Touch - Ionic 2 native error

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, 3dtouch

Has anyone ever used ionic native 3D Touch before? https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/3d-touch/

I have installed it through command line as said and pretty much copied the example however all I get is errors? Code is

```
import { ThreeDeeTouch, ThreeDeeTouchQuickAction, ThreeDeeTouchForceTouch } from '@ionic-native/three-dee-touch';

constructor(private threeDeeTouch: ThreeDeeTouch) { }

this.threeDeeTouch.isAvailable().then(isAvailable => console.log("3D Touch available? " + isAvailable));

this.threeDeeTouch.watchForceTouches()
  .subscribe(
    (data: ThreeDeeTouchForceTouch) => {
      console.log("Force touch %" + data.force);
      console.log("Force touch timestamp: " + data.timestamp);
      console.log("Force touch x: " + data.x);
      console.log("Force touch y: " + data.y);
    }
  );


let actions: Array<ThreeDeeTouchQuickAction> = [
  {
    type: 'checkin',
    title: 'Check in',
    subtitle: 'Quickly check in',
    iconType: 'Compose'
  },
  {
    type: 'share',
    title: 'Share',
    subtitle: 'Share like you care',
    iconType: 'Share'
  },
  {
    type: 'search',
    title: 'Search',
    iconType: 'Search'
  },
  {
    title: 'Show favorites',
    iconTemplate: 'HeartTemplate'
  }
];

this.threeDeeTouch.configureQuickActions(actions);

this.threeDeeTouch.onHomeIconPressed().subscribe(
 (payload) => {
   // returns an object that is the button you presed
   console.log('Pressed the ${payload.title} button')
   console.log(payload.type)

 }
)
```

I get unexpected token under `this`.

Also, within an ionic project where should you use this code? I currently have it on my home.ts but should it be in index.html? I don't really know. If anyone knows any ionic 2 apps that currently use it that would be great.

Comment: Can you update your question with your full home.ts code?

Comment: show us the error please